# Eckel Vol1, pg283, Incomplete type specification, what is the compiler doing?

Tags: c++

```
struct X;

struct Y {
  void f(X*);
};

struct X { //definition
private:
  int i;
public:
  friend void Y::f(X*);
  <SNIP'd>
};
```

> "struct `Y` has a member function `f()` that will modify an object of type `X`. This is a bit of a conundrum because the **C++ compiler requires you to declare everything before you can refer to it**, so struct `Y` must be declared before its member `Y::f(X*)` can be declared as a friend in struct `X`. But for `Y::f(X*)` to be declared struct `X` must be declared first!
>
> Here's the solution. Notice that `Y::f(X*)` takes the address of an `X` object. This is critical because **the compiler always knows how to pass an address, which is of a fixed size regardless of the object being passed**, even if it doesn't have full information about the size of the type."

So here we have:

```
struct X; struct Y { ... }; struct X { ... };
```

My question is this:

1. Why does the compiler insist that `X` be declared incompletely as: `struct X;`??

   After all, as the author notes: "compiler always knows how to pass an address 
   which is of a fixed size." This is just a declaration that tells the compiler that `X` is a struct and soon to follow, so why is the compiler so insistent that you type out the letters: struct `X`; after all I'm not using `X` per se?? There's no assembly language code being generated at that point. and when it reads the `X*` surely it can tell that it's an address(pointer).. why is: `struct X;` needed?

   The whole point of declaring functions is for type checking before actual 
   usage. So if I do:

   ```
    int foo(void); foo(30);
   ```

   and the compiler will howl. But in the above, if I don't say: `struct X;` what difference does it make? Is he just checking my spelling of `X` (the function-name)?
2. Why doesn't reversing the placement of struct Y and X work? Like so:
   `struct Y; struct X { ... }; struct Y { ... };`
   I get:

   > error: invalid use of incomplete type `'struct main()::Y'`

   Obviously, the compiler isn't satisfied with my incomplete type specification for 
   `Y` (`struct Y;`). But what precious little nugget of info is missing?? After
   all struct `Y`; should tell the compiler that `Y` is soon to follow (same as doing
   what we were doing in Q1: `struct X; struct Y {}; struct X{};` )
3. Why does the author refer to struct `X` as a definition? If i do:
   `struct X { ... };` this is surely a declaration? And when I instantiate the
   structure like so: `X` foo; then it's a definition? Correct?
4. How do I do this:

   ```
   struct X {
     friend void Y::f(X*);
     void f(Y*);
   };

   struct Y {
     friend void X::f(Y*);
     void f(X*);
   };
   ```

Comment: Whenever you start thinking about C++ semantics in terms of assembly, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the compiler insist that X be declared incompletely as: struct X?? After all, as the author notes: "compiler always knows how to pass an address which is of a fixed size.."

You don't: this works too:

```
struct Y { void f(struct X*); };

class X {
    int i;
    friend void Y::f(X*);
};
```

What *else* do you propose?

Also, you don't even have to have the complete type, when passing by value **unless you *actually* define the method**:

```
struct Y { void f(struct X); };

// too early:    
void Y::f(struct X) { /* whoops compile error */ }

class X {
    int i;
    friend void Y::f(X);
};

// ok here:
void Y::f(X) { /* compile success */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

> After all, as the author notes: "compiler always knows how to pass an address which is of a fixed size.." This is just a declaration that tells the compiler that X is a struct and soon to follow, so why is the compiler so insistent that you type out the letters: `struct X;` after all i'm not using X per se?? There's no assembly language code being generated at that point.. and when it reads the "X*" surely it can tell that it's an address(pointer).. why is: `struct X;` needed??

The author isn't telling you *all* the nasty details. The compiler knows how to pass a pointer (an address), if it knows what kind of object `X` is. The language allows some pointers, like pointer to `char` on a word-adressable machine, or a pointer to function, to be of a different size.

Therefore, you must tell the compiler that `X` is a `struct` and not a function or a typedef for a built in type.